# How to transfer data from a text file to excel using TalenD

Tags: talend

I don't know anything about TalenD but have to work,so if anybody can help me out in letting me know how to create mapping and transfer data from suppose a txt file to .xls.

Thanks In advance

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the format of the txt file.

Then you need to find the appropriate talend input component and read in the data.

You should make clear what your specification of your output format are.

For example if you need conditional formatting or complicated dynamic formulas, you need to find a good Talend output component, for example tFileExcelSheetOutput [1].

Otherwise you could use the standard tFileOutputExcel component.

You would use tMap to map the input to the output and depending on your transformation requirements you might also need additional components.

I would recommend looking at Talend on demand seminars which should be freely available from their website to get yourself familar with Talend Studio. Then you can consult the component reference, which is also integrated into Talend Studio.

If you need further assistance you can describe what you tried and what part exactly doesn't work.

[1] http://talendforge.org/exchange/index.php?eid=1257&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1